# Return multiple react components from a javascript function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to build a table dynamically in React. The cells in the table will come from the `dataset` property on an incoming HTML object. The table will have two columns - the name of the attribute and the value of the attribute.

This function builds the outer table:

```
  buildDataList = () => (
    <Scroll>
      <Table isStriped key={this.claimCountLimitPerFin} >
        <Table.Header>
          <Table.HeaderCell content="Name" minWidth="medium" />
          <Table.HeaderCell content="Value" minWidth="medium" />
        </Table.Header>
        <Table.MultiSelectableRows // this is probably not necessary?
          maxSelectionCount={10}
        >
          {this.buildTableRows2()}

        </Table.MultiSelectableRows>
      </Table>
    </Scroll>
  );
```

This is the function that I'm calling to build the `TableRows`:

```
  buildTableRows2 = () => {
    Object.keys(this.props.dataset).forEach(datum => <Table.Row
      id={datum}
      key={`ROW_${datum}`}
    >
      {this.buildTextCell(datum)}
      {this.buildTextCell(this.props.dataset[datum])}
    </Table.Row>);
  }
```

I cannot figure out how to get `buildTableRows2` to return all of the `TableRow`s! It isn't returning any, though I see that it is looping through all the attributes of dataset as I expect. I tried wrapping it in a React fragment, but that didn't work. I can't think of any other possible solutions. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two problems in your code:

- You are not returning anything from the `buildTableRows2()` function. You need to add a `return` keyword before `Object.keys()` inside `buildTableRows2()` function.
- `.forEach()` method doesn't returns anything, you will need to use `.map()` method.

Change the `buildTableRows2()` function as shown below:

```
buildTableRows2 = () => {
    return Object.keys(this.props.dataset).map(datum => (
       <Table.Row
         id={datum}
         key={`ROW_${datum}`}
       >
         {this.buildTextCell(datum)}
         {this.buildTextCell(this.props.dataset[datum])}
       </Table.Row>
    );
}
```

Comment: Thank you!!! Changing it to be the way you suggested worked!